# What happens to a Guru when he dies?

Tags: krishna, guru, gaudiya-vaishnavism

What happens to a Guru when he dies in Gaudiya System?
For example, some guru dies, who will be the next guru? His disciple or whom?

Comment: Yeah, I think in all sects of Hinduism disciples succeed gurus.

Comment: then how to choose guru if our guru dies?? can we change our guru then??

Comment: Do you want to know how Successor is decided?

Comment: No, there need not be a successor.

Comment: yes @TheDestroyer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Guru-shishya** tradition, lineage, or Parampara denotes a 
succession of teachers and disciples in the traditional Hinduism culture.

The tradition of spiritual relationship and mentoring where teachings 
are transmitted from a Guru (Teacher) to a Shishya (Disciple) .
Such knowledge, whether it be Vedic, Agamic, Architectural, 
Musical or Spiritual, is carried through the relationship 
between the Teacher( Guru) and the Disciple (Shishya). This 
relationship is based on the efforts of the Guru, and the respect, 
commitment, devotion and obedience of the Disciple, is the best method 
for spiritual or material  knowledge to be carried forward.

We generally  make a slight distinction between **Gurukula** 
system and **Guru-Sishya Parampara**, though the way of teaching & learning 
on principles, is  almost the same. The difference is that the 
Gurukula system can be compared to the present day residence or 
boarding schools. Thus, a group of students lives with and study 
under one single Guru, till they complete  their education.This is going on since Vedic times. By using this method, any form of art,music,dance etc., were taught.

**The Guru-sishya Parampara** is considered as learning on a one-to-
one basis (The teacher and a Single student), the student being living 
in the teacher’s house and learning without any specific timing , as per the teacher’s convenience. And meantime helping the teacher in his day today works.

**The Gurukula system** is an effective medium to preserve 
traditional art forms without losing the values for this many 
generations. The family tradition of imparting education was also there. In this system a teacher teaches to group of multiple students. Student being living 
in the teacher’s house and learning.And meantime helping the teacher in his day today works.

In Advaita tradition:

> **नारायण समारंभाम् व्यासः शंकर मध्यमां |
>
>       अस्मदाचार्य पर्यन्तां वंदे गुरु परम्पराम् ||**
>
> nārāyaṇa samāraṃbhām vyāsaḥ śaṃkara madhyamāṃ |
>  asmadācārya paryantāṃ vaṃde guru paramparām
>
> Meaning: salutation to the lineage starting with lord Narayana, with
>   Ved- Vyasa and Adi Sankara in the middle and continuing up to my
>   immediate teacher.
>
> **ध्यान मूलं गुरु मूर्ति , पूजा मूलं गुरु पदम् ।
>
>   मन्त्र मूलं गुरु :वाक्यं , मोक्ष मूलं गुरु कृपा ।।** 
>   dhyāna mūlaṃ guru mūrti , pūjā mūlaṃ guru padam ।
>   mantra mūlaṃ guru :vākyaṃ , mokṣa mūlaṃ guru kṛpā ।।
>
> Meaning: Guru's murti/idol/body is the object of meditation, his feet, the objects of worship, his words the objects of chanting. All this is
>   because in his grace lies the source of liberation.

Usually, first guru in any lineage defines the goals and broadly gives paths to achieve those. **(Lakshya Nirdesa)** The subsequent ones define paths that suit the times, in a way that they lead to the goals set by the first teacher or Guru and are not in conflict with the philosophy of the tradition **(Marga Nirdesa)**. Guru, the teacher **Teacher is accorded highest respect, and is equated to God**. The famous sanskrut verse tells us -:

> गुरुर्ब्रह्मा गुरुर्विष्णुर्गुरुर्देवो महेश्वरः ।
>   गुरुः साक्षात् परं ब्रह्म तस्मै श्रीगुरवे नमः ॥
>
> gururbrahmā gururviṣṇurgururdevo maheśvaraḥ ।
>   guruḥ sākṣāt paraṃ brahma tasmai śrīgurave namaḥ ॥
>
> **Meaning:** Guru is Brahma, Vishnu and Mahesha, in fact guru is Prabrahma
>   himself, the Brahman, the Absolute. Salutations to such guru.

**We do not regard the Guru as a human being . Hence, he is not a body; and therefore, he does not die. The immortal Guru maintains an immortal relationship with the shishya.**

> Fact is  that **every learning experience need not necessarily have the
>   same guru,** is best brought out by the example of **Avadhoot Dattatreya** 
>   who acknowledged more than **30 gurus** as his preceptors. For him, any
>   person who brought about his enlightenment was a guru.

**Shrimad Bhagvad Gita** too highlights the highest values of the guru-shishya parampara. In an act of reverence, Arjuna shoots arrows as a homage at the feet of his teachers, Dronacharya and Bhishma Pitahmaha.

> shishya learns not only in the physical presence of the guru, but also in the absence of the guru.

**Shishya therefore must always  remember his guru and his teaching and follw the path accordingly** and spread the teachings of his for goodness for others.

There are many Guru-Sishya paramparas in Sanatana Dharma, which have come down uninterrupted over time. All the Vidyas and literature like **Vedas, Vedangas, Darsanas and Dharma sutras** have come down as Guru-Sishya paramparas. For example branches of Veda have come down as Guru-Sishya paramparas. **Various schools of spiritual philosophy such as Advaita, Vishishta Advaita and Dvaita have come down as Guru-Sishya paramparas.**

http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Guru-Sishya_parampara and various other internet sources.

Comment: My answer includes all " paramparas" hene includes  Gaudiya  pampara also

Comment: My answer includes all " paramparas" I don't think you covered every guru parampara. Sri Sampradaya has the sholka Laxminatha Samarambham Nathayamuni madhyamam Asmad Acharya paryantam vande Guru Paramparam.